# Why is Emacs not aligning text?

Tags: align, bidirectional-support

When I started Emacs with `emacs -q`

I customized the variable "Bidi Paragraph Direction" to 1 (right to left)

It only affected this "Customize .." buffer and the bottom buffer. One of them is illustrated in the following picture:

[image: Emacs only changes this page]

Other buffers are left to right.

[image: Emacs does not change this buffer]

I tried this without `-q` and it didn't work either after restarting Emacs.

My `emacs-version` is GNU Emacs 25.2.2

Comment: What about the customization of `bidi-display-reordering`?